# Run jQuery/Javascript Function w/GSAP only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap, scrolltop, scrollto

I have a function that scrolls down/snaps to a div after the user starts to scroll (to avoid them having to manually scroll down to where the main content starts). I have used some GSAP to achieve this, however I don't think that will make much difference with the solution to this problem. However, while this function does exactly what I'd like, It won't then allow the user to scroll back up. It just glitches a little bit, as if I'm fighting with the function to scroll back up. I've tried a variety of answers from all the "run only once questions" on here, but none seem to work in this situation.

I want to basically kill the function after the first time it is initiated, or to tweak the function to only work on the first scroll at the top of the page (though I appreciate this would be much more complicated).

Thank you in advance of any help.

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  function headScrollToDiv() {
    var dHeight = $(window).height();
    if (dHeight >= $(this).scrollTop()) {
      gsap.to(window, 0.4, { scrollTo: ".buffer" });
    }
  }
  headScrollToDiv();
});
```

Comment: [Relevant GSAP forum thread](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/24423-how-to-snap-instantly-on-slight-scroll/).

Comment: Thank you! Despite my jumbled explanation, this has gotten me to exactly where I needed! Have a great day!